# NetBook's system recovery related to saving data

Tags: laptop, boot, netbook, system-restore, eee-pc

When I try to boot my net book Eee goes into windows pre instalation environment and gives a message that I may lose all my data during recovery. It suggests to back up data before recovery. I can not pass this screen.

How can I save my data on this drive? I tried  to use F2 on boot, but do not know the steps to avoid the screen above?

Is my drive damaged or is it trying to recover?

I appreciate help on this matter.

Comment: have you tried a flash drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering files from laptop with XP that won't boot](http://superuser.com/questions/78874/recovering-files-from-laptop-with-xp-that-wont-boot)

Comment: Not related... This is about recovering the data.

Comment: You should try to boot from some other media, like a cd then copy everything on external, or use a windows disc that will back up during install

Answer (score 1):

***How can I save my data on this drive? I tried to use F2 on boot, but do not know the steps to avoid the screen above?*** I suggest you try booting from [something like this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download), use that environment to backup your data (or even to test your hardware for the data).

You can also try booting [this](http://download.berlios.de/rescatux/rescatux_cdrom_usb_hybrid_i386_486-amd64_0.29.iso) to see if you just managed to mess up your bootloader (doesn't really sound like that though).

***Is my drive damaged or is it trying to recover?*** There isn't enough information given to really know.